# gulp-typescript: ошибка

Tags: gulp, typescript

Добрый день. Пытаюсь транспайлить typescript.

Имеется следующий gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var small = require('small').gulp;
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var tsProject = typescript.createProject('lib/tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('typescript')
})

gulp.task('compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('lib/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(small('index.js', {
            externalResolve: ['node_modules'],
            globalModules: {
                "crypto": {
                    standalone: "undefined"
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('release', ['compile'], function() {
    return gulp.src('static/scripts/scripts.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compile'], function() {

});
```

в tsconfig.json лежит следующее:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    }
}
```

при запуске gulp compile получаю

```
typescript.js:11462
});
^

Syntax error: Unexpected token }
```

Не могу понять эту ошибку, в самом gulpfile, понятно, со скобками всё хорошо

Comment: а причем gulpfile если ошибка в typescript.js.. и Вам не помогут, недостаточно данных, а выжимать из Вас показывать то, а затем то, тоже думаю мало кому интересно.

Comment: по-моему, должно быть понятно, что typescript.js это стандартный модуль, его писал не я. Насколько понимаю, это то, что подключилось по require('typescript'). Непонятно, вы хотите, чтобы я привёл здесь исходный код этого модуля? думаю, что здесь какая-то ошибка всё-таки в gulpfile, по крайней мере, оно появляется при запуске задачи gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете ts.projects() и в него же передаете его же.
Передавайте в пайп свой проект, а не в ts(проект).